# bool operator ++ and --

Tags: c++, boolean, increment

Today while writing some Visual C++ code I have come across something which has surprised me. It seems C++ supports ++ (increment) for bool, but not -- (decrement). It this just a random decision, or there is some reason behind this?

This compiles:

```
static HMODULE hMod = NULL;
static bool once = false;
if (!once++)
    hMod = LoadLibrary("xxx");
```

This does not:

```
static HMODULE hMod = NULL;
static bool once = true;
if (once--)
    hMod = LoadLibrary("xxx");
```

Comment: hm, same for xcode and gcc compiler

Comment: Yep, `++once` and `once++` work with gcc, but not the decrements.

Comment: Maybe retag "history" instead of "operator-keyword", so this is grouped with all the other fun explanations as to why various crazy things are reasonable if you consider the history? :)

Comment: Note as of C++17 the pre-increment operator for `bool` is deprecated, [souce](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec).

Comment: this can be replaced with `std::exchange(once,false)` (note: *not* atomic), if you want something non-deprecated.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

It comes from the history of using integer values as booleans.

If `x` is an `int`, but I am using it as a boolean as per `if(x)...` then incrementing will mean that whatever its truth value before the operation, it will have a truth-value of `true` after it (barring overflow).

However, it's impossible to predict the result of `--` given knowledge only of the truth value of `x`, as it could result in `false` (if the integral value is 1) or `true` (if the integral value is anything else - notably this includes 0 [`false`] and 2 or more [`true`]).

So as a short-hand `++` worked, and `--` didn't.

`++` is allowed on bools for compatibility with this, but its use is deprecated in the standard and it was removed in C++17.

---

This assumes that I **only** use `x` as an boolean, meaning that overflow can't happen until I've done `++` often enough to cause an overflow on it's own. Even with char as the type used and `CHAR_BITS` something low like 5, that's 32 times before this doesn't work any more (that's still argument enough for it being a bad practice, I'm not defending the practice, just explaining why it works) for a 32-bit `int` we of course would have to use `++` 2^32 times before this is an issue. With `--` though it will only result in `false` if I started with a value of 1 for `true`, or started with 0 and used `++` precisely once before.

This is different if we start with a value that is just a few below 0. Indeed, in such a case we might want `++` to result in the `false` value eventually such as in:

```
int x = -5;
while(++x)
  doSomething(x);
```

However, this example treats `x` as an `int` everywhere except the conditional, so it's equivalent to:

```
int x = -5;
while(++x != 0)
  doSomething(x);
```

Which is different to only using `x` as a boolean.

Comment: Thank you. Great to know I can still give answers people like on this, given how long it is since I've actually written a line of C++ :)

Comment: But if x were -1 (TRUE in some platforms like VB), ++x would be FALSE.

Comment: @James, in C and C++ that would be the case I was thinking of when I said ("barring overflow"). Actually in VB any non-zero has truth value TRUE (like in C), but they have -1 rather than 1 as the result of true boolean operations as then NOT(TRUE) is FALSE, NOT(FALSE) is TRUE, x OR TRUE is TRUE, x OR FALSE is x, x AND FALSE is FALSE and x AND TRUE is x, etc using the same operators for boolean and bit-wise operations (since VB assumes twos-complement so -1 is all 1 bits). However, this can cause some strange bugs in VB if the coder doesn't catch that 2 (true) AND 4 (true) results in 0 (false).

Comment: This answer doesn't feel very satisfying, as half of all `int` values fail the `++ -> always true` test.  If it was `unsigned int` on the other hand...

Comment: @Izkata no, every `int` value but one passes it. `-1` fails, and the maximum `unsigned int` fails, but all others result in true.

Comment: @JonHanna All negatives would eventually fail in a loop, so it has the same predictability as `--` with all positives...

Comment: @Izkata but with an integer being used solely as a bool, that won't happen until after overflow. As I say above, the overflow case is still a good reason to consider it bad practice, but that's a different matter to the fact that it was indeed used.

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` (not `CHAR_BITS`) is required to be least 8.

Comment: @KeithThompson I could be wrong, but I think it could be less prior to the 89 version.

Comment: @JonHanna: ANSI C89 was the first C standard. The ANSI C committee invented the `<limits.h>` header and the `CHAR_BIT` macro. Prior to that, I suppose there theoretically could have been implementations where `char` is narrower than 8 bits, but as far as I know there were none. In particular, K&R1 (published in 1978) lists 4 sample implementations, all of which have 8-bit or 9-bit `char`.

Comment: @KeithThompson machines with 5-bit bytes (or less) have been produced, though they would have already been old in 1989. A C implementation that didn't do something to have `char` different to the machine's byte size would hence have only 5 bits. It's a deliberately extreme example though.

Comment: @JonHanna: A conforming C implementation *must* have `CHAR_BIT >= 8`. The standard doesn't make allowances for targets where that's difficult. (You could have a non-conforming implementation, of course.)

Comment: @KeithThompson, or a pre-standard implementation. We are after all talking about something that isn't a good idea, but is supported because of the legacy of people doing it.

Comment: @JonHanna: Sure. A pre-standard implementation is almost by definition not conforming.

Answer (score 29):

**ANSI ISO IEC 14882 2003 (c++03):**

5.2.6-2

> The operand of postfix -- is
>   decremented analogously to the postfix
>   ++ operator, except that the operand shall not be of type bool. [Note: For
>   prefix increment and decrement, see
>   5.3.2. ]

And unsurprisingly...

5.3.2-2

> The operand of prefix -- is modified
>   by subtracting 1. The operand shall
>   not be of type bool. The requirements
>   on the operand of prefix -- and the
>   properties of its result are otherwise
>   the same as those of prefix ++. [Note:
>   For postfix increment and decrement,
>   see 5.2.6. ]

Also the 5.6.2-1 and 5.3.2-1 mention that ++ for bools shall be true and Annex D-1 says that ++ on bools in deprecated.

Comment: @BlueRaja: See Jon Hanna's answer.

Answer (score 11):

Due to historical reasons this was supported. But note that ...
*The use of an operand of type bool with the ++ operator is deprecated see Section 5.3.2 in the C++ Standard(n3092)*

**5.3.2 Increment and decrement [expr.pre.incr]**

- The operand of prefix ++ is modified
  by adding 1, or set to true if it is
  bool (this use is deprecated). The
  operand shall be a modifiable lvalue.
  The type of the operand shall be an
  arithmetic type or a pointer to a
  completely-defined object type. The
  result is the updated operand; it is
  an lvalue, and it is a bit-field if
  the operand is a bit-field. If x is
  not of type bool, the expression ++x
  is equivalent to x+=1 [ Note: see the
  discussions of addition (5.7) and
  assignment operators (5.17) for
  information on conversions. —end note
  ]
- The operand of prefix -- is modified
  by subtracting 1. The operand shall
  not be of type bool. The requirements
  on the operand of prefix -- and the
  properties of its result are
  otherwise the same as those of prefix
  ++.

Answer (score 3):

- With the old standards (C++98) it is not an error.
- With the new standards incrementing a boolean is deprecated. (C++11)
- You can use incrementation on a boolean until C++17.