# Why "++" operator over bool is defined?? however "--" is not in C++

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I was wondering why the `++` operator is defined over `bool`... however when I tried the `--`operator, it was not defined for `bool`..

Can someone please explain me the reason behind that?

Comment: fyi the increment use is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf4dy80a.aspx

> When a postfix or prefix ++ operator is applied to a variable of type
>   bool, the variable is set to true. The postfix or prefix -- operator
>   cannot be applied to a variable of this type.

Comment: This answer does not address the question: Why?

Comment: @Lii In a sense it does...  "You can't" because the documentation says you can't. :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, Jerry: Those are true statements but they don't answer the question! Why was the language designed this way?

Comment: @Lii You can ask the "designer"

Comment: @Lii Write to Bjarne and ask him.  Though, honestly, it does make sense.  If I increment false, it will become true.  If I decrement, however, am I making something more false??   Or, how do I evaluate true?  Non-zero?  Are sub-zero values false?

Comment: @Lii  Probably from when `false==0`, and `true!=0`. Which gives us (using integers) `++false==true`, `++true==true`. And then the surprising results `--false==true`, and most suprising `--true=={true or false}`.

Comment: These are real attempts to answers! Similar things are put forward in [the question of which this one is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450420/bool-operator-and).

Answer (score 2):

From the Standard 5.2.6.1

> The value of the operand object is modified by
>   adding 1 to it, unless the object is of type bool, in which case it is set to true. [ Note: this use is deprecated,
>   see Annex D. —end note ]

And 5.2.6.2 emphasis mine

> The operand of postfix -- is decremented analogously to the postfix ++ operator, **except that the operand
>   shall not be of type bool**. [ Note: For prefix increment and decrement, see 5.3.2. —end note ]

And Annex D

> D.1 Increment operator with bool operand [depr.incr.bool]
>   1 The use of an operand of type bool with the ++ operator is deprecated (see 5.3.2 and 5.2.6).

So in turn the reason you can't is because it is against the standard.